# Proper way to log things when using Pytorch Lightning DDP

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I was wondering what is the proper way of logging metrics when using DDP. I noticed that if I want to print something inside `validation_epoch_end` it will be printed twice when using 2 GPUs. I was expecting `validation_epoch_end` to be called only on rank 0 and to receive the outputs from all GPUs, but I am not sure this is correct anymore. Therefore I have several questions:

1. `validation_epoch_end(self, outputs)` - When using DDP does every subprocess receive the data processed from the current GPU or data processed from all GPUs, i.e. does the input parameter `outputs` contains the outputs of the entire validation set, from all GPUs?
2. If `outputs` is GPU/process specific what is the proper way to calculate any metric on the entire validation set in `validation_epoch_end` when using DDP?

I understand that I can solve the printing by checking `self.global_rank == 0` and printing/logging only in that case, however I am trying to get a deeper understanding of what I am printing/logging in this case.

Here is a code snippet from my use case. I would like to be able to report f1, precision and recall on the entire validation dataset and I am wondering what is the correct way of doing it when using DDP.

```
    def _process_epoch_outputs(self,
                               outputs: List[Dict[str, Any]]
                               ) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:
        """Creates and returns tensors containing all labels and predictions

        Goes over the outputs accumulated from every batch, detaches the
        necessary tensors and stacks them together.

        Args:
            outputs (List[Dict])
        """
        all_labels = []
        all_predictions = []

        for output in outputs:
            for labels in output['labels'].detach():
                all_labels.append(labels)

            for predictions in output['predictions'].detach():
                all_predictions.append(predictions)

        all_labels = torch.stack(all_labels).long().cpu()
        all_predictions = torch.stack(all_predictions).cpu()

        return all_predictions, all_labels

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs: List[Dict[str, Any]]) -> None:
        """Logs f1, precision and recall on the validation set."""

        if self.global_rank == 0:
            print(f'Validation Epoch: {self.current_epoch}')

        predictions, labels = self._process_epoch_outputs(outputs)
        for i, name in enumerate(self.label_columns):

            f1, prec, recall, t = metrics.get_f1_prec_recall(predictions[:, i],
                                                             labels[:, i],
                                                             threshold=None)
            self.logger.experiment.add_scalar(f'{name}_f1/Val',
                                              f1,
                                              self.current_epoch)
            self.logger.experiment.add_scalar(f'{name}_Precision/Val',
                                              prec,
                                              self.current_epoch)
            self.logger.experiment.add_scalar(f'{name}_Recall/Val',
                                              recall,
                                              self.current_epoch)

            if self.global_rank == 0:
                print((f'F1: {f1}, Precision: {prec}, '
                       f'Recall: {recall}, Threshold {t}'))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Questions

> validation_epoch_end(self, outputs) - When using DDP does every
> subprocess receive the data processed from the current GPU or data
> processed from all GPUs, i.e. does the input parameter outputs
> contains the outputs of the entire validation set, from all GPUs?

**Data processed from the current GPU only**, outputs are not synchronized, there is only `backward` synchronization (gradients are synchronized during training and distributed to replicas of models residing on each GPU).

Imagine that all of the outputs were passed from `1000` GPUs to this poor master, it could give it an OOM very easily

> If outputs is GPU/process specific what is the proper way to calculate
> any metric on the entire validation set in validation_epoch_end when
> using DDP?

According to [documentation](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/lightning_module.html#validating-with-dataparallel) (emphasis mine):

> When validating using a accelerator that splits data from each batch
> across GPUs, sometimes you might need to aggregate them on the **master
> GPU** for processing (dp, or ddp2).

And here is accompanying code (`validation_epoch_end` would receive accumulated data across multiple GPUs from single step in this case, also **see the comments**):

```
# Done per-process (GPU)
def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = batch
    y_hat = self.model(x)
    loss = F.cross_entropy(y_hat, y)
    pred = ...
    return {'loss': loss, 'pred': pred}

# Gathered data from all processes (per single step)
# Allows for accumulation so the whole data at the end of epoch
# takes less memory
def validation_step_end(self, batch_parts):
    gpu_0_prediction = batch_parts.pred[0]['pred']
    gpu_1_prediction = batch_parts.pred[1]['pred']

    # do something with both outputs
    return (batch_parts[0]['loss'] + batch_parts[1]['loss']) / 2

def validation_epoch_end(self, validation_step_outputs):
   for out in validation_step_outputs:
       # do something with preds
```

### Tips

> **Focus on per-device calculations and as small number of between-GPU transfers as possible**

- Inside `validation_step` (or `training_step` if that's what you want, this is general) calculate `f1`, `precision`, `recall` and whatever else **on a per-batch basis**
- Returns those values (say, as a dict). Now you will return `3` numbers from each device instead of `(batch, outputs)` (which could be significantly larger)
- Inside `validation_step_end` get those `3` values (actually `(2, 3)` if you have 2 GPUs) and sum/take mean of them and return `3` values
- Now `validation_epoch_end` will get `(steps, 3)` values that you can use to accumulate

It would be even better if instead of operating on list of values during `validation_epoch_end` you could accumulate them in another `3` values (say you have a lot of validation steps, the list could grow too large), but this should be enough.

AFAIK PyTorch-Lightning doesn't do this (e.g. instead of adding to `list`, apply some accumulator directly), but I might be mistaken, so any correction would be great.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, what you proposed is apparently only valid for DP and DDP2 as mentioned in the documentation. I tested this and confirmed that for DDP even if I use `validation_step_end` the outputs are always GPU specific...

Comment: @JovanAndonov there should be PyTorch "lower level" primitives you could probably work with if that's the case (might be a lot of headaches though).

Comment: A bit late, but you need to use [all_gather](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/latest/common/lightning_module.html#all-gather) for DDP